# openlayers polygon displays difference not union

Tags: openlayers, polygon, gwt-openlayers

In OpenLayers, I create a polygon consisting of two LinearRing objects, using code of the form (this is in Java+GWT, but the same principle applies to JS):

```
List<LinearRing> linearRingList = new ArrayList<LinearRing>();

List<Point> points1 = new ArrayList<Point>();
... populate points1 ...;
linearRingList.add(new LinearRing(points1.toArray(new Point[points.size()])));

List<Point> points2 = new ArrayList<Point>();
... populate points2 ...;
linearRingList.add(new LinearRing(points2.toArray(new Point[points.size()])));

Polygon poly = new Polygon(linearRingList.toArray(new LinearRing[linearRingList.size()]));
VectorFeature feature = new VectorFeature(poly);
myLayer.addFeature(feature);
```

When I view this layer on a map, if the polygons defined by points1 and points2 overlap, I see a hole:

[polygon hole http://www.jackhollow.co.uk/misc/polygon.png](http://www.jackhollow.co.uk/misc/polygon.png)

I'm seeing the "xor" of the two polygons, where I want to see the "or" of them instead, ie with that hole in the middle filled in green.

How do I do this?  I'm sure it's just a display issue in Openlayers, but I can't find a flag to control it anywhere.

The original two polygons are as:

[polygon hole http://www.jackhollow.co.uk/misc/polygon2.png](http://www.jackhollow.co.uk/misc/polygon2.png)

if displayed together on a single layer they overlap, but Openlayers is not filling in the intersecting parts.

Comment: I can assure you that it will not be an issue with the OpenLayers renderers. I have worked with polygons with huge numbers of points and large numbers of inner holes, and they have always displayed correctly in Chrome, IE and Firefox, ie, with both VML and SVG.  I am not entirely clear what you are looking for. Do you want both the green Polygons and the hole in the middle as one Polygon? Without seeing the date it will be hard to help further, but there are Java libraries available which will merge polygons in any way.

Comment: I would expect the single polygon object I've created ("poly" in that code) to appear as two overlapping green polygons on the layer, whereas what I see are the two polygons overlapping, minus the part where they intersect.

Comment: Without seeing the actual polygon it is impossible to know

Comment: I added an image of the two separate shapes which would make up points1 and points2 in my code snippet.  The first image shows what I see on the screen when that code is run, ie displaying the layer consisting of those two List<Points> as a LinearRing - where the two shapes overlap on the screen, Openlayers leaves a hole, rather than filling in that hole.

Comment: I have posted a solution to your issue. Apologies, I was half asleep last night, and got confused by the mixture of Java and Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding both LinearRings to the same Polygon. All rings, after the first, are defined as inner rings of a polygon (ie, internal holes), which explains the strange intersection behavior you are seeing -- an attempt to draw an inner ring, which is not in fact inside. See components in the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html).  To fix your problem, you need to create two separate Geometry.Polygons and two separate Feature.Vectors and add both of these to your Layer.Vector.

```
 var linearRing1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(pointList1);
 var feature1 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
          new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing1]));

 var linearRing2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(pointList2);
 var feature2 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
          new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing2]));


var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("layername");
layer.addFeatures([feature1, feature2]);
```

where you create your point lists as before. You can also add attributes and styles to each feature vector, or a style to the layer vector, but I left this out for clarity.

There is no explicit check in OpenLayers that your geometry is correct, ie, that the inner rings are actually inside the outer ring, so if you hand an array of line strings to a polygon constructor, an attempt will be made to convert this to the appropriate SVG or VML objects, with unpredictable results.

Comment: That's great! I see I was misunderstanding the LinearRings - this solved the problem.